# Validators.email not working for french characters in Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, forms, email, angular-reactive-forms

I was using validators.email pattern to check the email but it is somehow not working for french characters. How I can support french characters in email?

Below is email address I was trying
ÀÁÂÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÙÚÛÜÝ@ÀÁÂÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÙÚÛÜÝ.ÀÁÂÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÙÚÛÜÝ

Below is stackblitz which I was trying.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-email-validation-1vlpcv

Answer (score 1):

Hello you have to create a custom validator and create   a regex for this validator.
Using something like this `Validators.pattern("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$")]),`